# Проблема с интерфейсами

Tags: java

Не могу сообразить в чем проблема, выдает: "return type void is not compatible with string interface java",
я что то читал про одинаковые сигнатуры методов но так и не понял. Как мне решить данную проблему или в какую сторону копать.

```
public class Student implements Printable { 


    Student() {
         ...
    }


    public void doing() {
        System.out.printf(" что то делает ");
    }
}

class StudentDetails extends Student implements Printable {

    StudentDetails() {
        super()
         ...
    }

    public void doing(){
        System.out.println("делает что то вдобавок");
    }
}

interface Printable {

    void doing();

}

class Main {

public static void main(String[] arg) {
    Student st1 = new Student();
    Student st2 = new Student();
    Student st3 = new Student();
    Student st4 = new Student();
    Student st5 = new Student();

    Student[] students = new Student[5];
    students[0] = st1;
    students[1] = st2;
    students[2] = st3;
    students[3] = st4;
    students[4] = st5;

    for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(students[i].doing());
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.out.println` ожидает, что вы передадите строку как параметр, а метод `doing` не возвращает ничего, поскольку он `void`.

Попробуйте

```
for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
    students[i].doing();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
    students[i].doing();
}
```